# Installing Bookmark fails: "No matching distribution found for Bookmark"

Tags: python, django, pip, pycharm, bookmarks

I tried to `pip install Bookmark(and opencv)` but couldn't install it in `Pycharm` Terminal(Professional and Community)

I don't understand why it won't install. Please help me

My python version is 3.8.1 64 bit ( also try 3.7.6 64 bit) 
I tried following command.

```
(venv) C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled>pip install Bookmark
```

The message I am getting is as follows.

> Collecting Bookmark
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Bookmark (from versions: )
>       No matching distribution found for Bookmark

Comment: what is `Bookmark` ? To install `opencv` you have to use `pip install opencv-python`

Comment: you could check `pip -V` to see what version you runs. You can also check `pip search Bookmark` maybe it uses different name.

Comment: Bookmark is api for django , i tried pip install opencv-python but can't installing

Comment: what is next step after pip search Bookmark?

Comment: check list and see if your module has name `Bookmark` or something different. I see `Bookmark` is some `Web bookmark manager` but there is nothing about `django`. Maybe your module has name `django-bookmarks` ?

Comment: do you get exactly the same error for `opencv-python` or something different?

Comment: do you know where you found this bookmark package for django ? cause pip show there 2 different bookmark packages so we can't know which package you referring to

Comment: i try 'pip install django-bookmarks' but i can use 'import Bookmark '

Comment: i want to import Bookmark

Comment: yes please link us where you found this bookmark package